# self.window cornerRadius - without statusbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, cornerradius

I want to have rounded corners on my whole app, I used:

```
[self.window.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];
[self.window.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
self.window.layer.opaque = NO;
```

But now my StatusBar has roundCorners, how can I use self.window without statusbar?

Comment: Have you tried `self.ViewController.view`?

Comment: I use a SideMenu, so when you use that menu you swipe the first view away which results in no corner radius on right.

Answer (score 3):

```
[self.window.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];
[self.window.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
self.window.layer.opaque = NO;
```

Will round the corner of the window not it's subview.

Please change the value of `5` to `45` to see clear effects as below

```
[self.window.layer setCornerRadius:45.0];
[self.window.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
self.window.layer.opaque = NO;
```

Comment: I know that is the problem but I don't know how to fix it.